# Why doesn't work Variable length array as a globally?

Tags: c, gcc, variable-length-array

If I write variable length array as a locally, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=1;
    int a[i];
    printf("%zu",sizeof(a));
}
```

It working fine in GCC compiler.

But, If I write Variable length array as a globally, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i=1;
int a[i];
int main()
{
    printf("%zu",sizeof(a));
}
```

Then, GCC compiler gives following an error:

```
prog.c:4:5: error: variably modified 'a' at file scope
  int a[i];
```

Comment: If the array is declared with a constant '1' the compiler should declare the array of size 1, I haven't tried it buts that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: @SPlatten - In C++. In C a `const int` is not a constant expression.

Comment: I found a way to declare a variable length array globally, this is not straightforward but doable. See my aswer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360394/declaring-a-variable-length-array-as-a-global-variable-in-c/56924075#56924075

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From standard [6.7.6.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p2)

> If an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread
>   storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.

Answer (score 6):

It's not allowed because unless it is restricted to the extreme, it could be exceptionally error prone. Consider this:

```
extern const int sz; // Another TU
int a[sz];
```

The size of the array depends on the initialization order between it and `sz` (which in our example is in another transnational unit). It could produce a 0 sized array (ill-formed). The correctness of programs being built should not depend on such things.

So if we limit its size to variables in the current TU only, we end up with:

```
const int sz = 10;
int a[sz];
```

But why use a VLA at all in this case? Just specify the size with the constant expression 10.

It's just not a useful feature. Not to mention, as @M.M pointed out, that it goes against the design goal of easily allowing static data to be pre-built into the binary.

Comment: Also the static initialization restrictions are designed to allow for the static data area to be preconstructed and built into the binary ; OP suggestion is incompatible with this

Comment: @M.M - Excellent point. I nabbed it into the post.

Comment: What about creating a static `int` array inside a function using the length of a compile-time known array of strings?  The compiler knows how long the array is, it can be passed as a `const`, and so it isn't variable-length.  Yet it refuses to compile with a bogus error.  C _should_ allow `const` sizes for fixed-length arrays, but it doesn't by pretending they are variable-length, thus copping out.

Answer (score 5):

You already [have the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47809345/2173917), but just to elaborate on *why* part, let me add my two cents.

First, about *lifetime*: (quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.4/P2)

> The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is
>   guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists, has a constant address,33) and retains
>   its last-stored value throughout its lifetime.34)

Then, *static storage duration*: (quoting P3)

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier
>   `_Thread_local`, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the
>   program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

and , the *linkage*: (chapter §6.2.3/P5)

> [...] If
>   the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier,
>   its linkage is external.

So, in this case, `a` is to have static storage duration.

Now, by definition, VLA dimension is acquired at *runtime*, so there's noway compiler can know and allocate memory/storage and initialize it at the *beginning* (prior to program startup, as required for static storage duration), hence this is a conflict.

As mentioned in `C11` chapter 6.7.6.2, standard **explicitly forbids** this.

> [...] If an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread storage
>   duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.

Answer (score 5):

Because the standard says so. But that isn't very helpful; the reason *why* this isn't allowed by the standard, is that all file scope variables must be initialized before main() is called. This in turn means that they must consist of compile-time constants only.

The purpose of a VLA is to grab the size in run-time. We can't have an array where the size is determined both at compile-time and run-time. If you have need for a variable size array at file scope, use a pointer and then in run-time have it point to an allocated array, such as for example an array allocated with malloc().